# Python- Unable to write to a csv-‘Type Error: “Delimiter” must be a 1-character string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe-df which contains the below values
**Key**          **Summary**                        **Area****Priority**
1   Verify if site is launching                     Homepage    High
2   Verify if Home page is launching correctly      Homepage    High
3   Verify if able to add fruits,veggies to cart      Cart     Medium
4   Verify if able to place an order                 Order      High

I am trying to load data to csv/tsv and I used the below line & it works fine

```
df.to_csv(“C\users\xxx\Documents\Output\FinalData.csv”,index=False)
df.to_tsv(“C\users\xxx\Documents\Output\FinalData.csv”,sep=’\t’,index=False)
```

When I send the above file to my downstream team, some times their EDW script is failing if there is a comma/ tab in any of the fields so they asked me to send the file with delimiter as ‘~|~’ or ‘~|’.
When I use the below code, I am getting error as ‘Type Error: “Delimiter” must be a 1-character string

a)  `df.to_csv(“C\users\xxx\Documents\Output\FinalData.csv”, sep=’~|~’,index=False)`   or

b)
separator=’,’

```
df.to_csv(“C\users\xxx\Documents\Output\FinalData.csv”, sep=’~|~’,index=False)
```

or

c)
separator=’,’

```
df.to_csv(“C\users\xxx\Documents\Output\FinalData.csv”, sep=’~|’,index=False)
```

Could you please suggest if anyways of writing data to a file with multiple delimiters or if there is anyother way of handling this scenario? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `to_csv()` method supports only a single-character string as a delimiter, the same is true for Python standard CSV library. So you should choose some single-digit delimiter and than write a script which will read the csv file (as a plain text) and replace chosen delimiters to ‘~|~’ or ‘~|’

Comment: Thank you, can you please share sample piece of code.